# UIViewController best practice - loading

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, viewdidload

I have a simple view controller with some UI outlets. I am using ARC I do additional setup in the `viewDidLoad` such as setting label properties, if statements to dynamically resize some components, etc. My question is is the `viewDidLoad`the best place to place this code? I've posted an example of some of the code I have in the method. Thanks.

```
self.messageTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
self.messageTitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.messageTitleLabel.minimumFontSize = 15.0f;
[self someMethodToReframeLabelHeight];
```

Comment: For stuff like that why not do that in interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, great place. Recall that in iOS, the system may unload your view due to memory pressure, and so you may get this message again later. Thus, having the code there that adjusts the newly loaded view is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

As commented out by David, yes it's perfect to perform additional setups here. But be aware that in `viewDidLoad` no geometry has been already set for its view. So, if you need to arrange the position of a subview within the controller's view use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As David H mentioned, `viewDidLoad` is a good place for memory reasons- if your application receives a memory warning, your views will be set up again the next time they are loaded. Another important reason to use `viewDidLoad`, though, is that if you try to put the above code in `init` or `initWithWhatever:`, you will encounter some strange problems. The reason is that in the `init` method, the view has not yet been created and awakened from its .nib, and accessing it from there will disrupt the entire view controller cycle. If you aren't using a .nib, you can also do some basic setup in `-loadView`. Just make sure you call `super` any time you override one of these methods.